# Custom Editor Template not working for Kendo UI for ASP.NET Core Scheduler widget

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using Kendo UI for ASP.NET Core in an ASP.NET Core MVC Web application.

I followed [this example](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/scheduler/scheduler-custom-editor) to use a custom editor template for my Kendo UI Scheduler.

I made sure my EventViewModel implements ISchedulerEvent.

I created an editor template (w/ EventViewModel) just like they did under Views/Events/EditorTemplates/CustomEditorTemplate.cshtml. (I am starting simple with just 2 fields to make sure it works).

```
@model EventViewModel
    @{
        //required in order to render validation attributes
        ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
    }

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @{
        ViewContext.FormContext = null;
    }
```

I also created a view to place the Scheduler (w/ EventViewModel) itself on:
Views/Events/Index.cshtml:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<EventViewModel>()
      .Name("scheduler")
      .Height(600)
      .Views(views => {
          views.DayView();
          views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
          views.MonthView();
          views.AgendaView();
      })
      .Editable(editable => {
          editable.TemplateName("CustomEditorTemplate");
      })
      .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
      .DataSource(d => d
          .Model(m => {
              m.Id(f => f.Id);
              m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
          })
          .Read("Events_Read", "Events")
          .Create("Events_Create", "Events")
          .Destroy("Events_Destroy", "Events")
          .Update("Events_Update", "Events")
      )
      )
```

The CustomEditorTemplate I am specifying gets completely ignored. I end up with a window that has every single field that ISchedulerEvent has. Does this not work for ASP.NET Core MVC yet?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this thread](https://www.telerik.com/forums/scheduler-edit-template-mvc), this behavior isn't supported out of the box.

You can handle the double click event yourself to open a popup not related to the scheduler however. You can see an example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/adaz).